# Windows SEH and memory management

Tags: visual-c++, exception

I'm writing some code that handles Windows structured exceptions (in my case using [`_set_se_translator()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z4bw5h5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to convert them to C++ exceptions).

The thing that is worrying me is the extensive use of pointers in the exception information I get passed when an exception occurrs. I get passed a pointer to an [`_EXCEPTION_POINTERS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) struct. It contains pointers to two other structs, one of which possibly contains another pointer field that makes that object basically a linked-list.

Where does the memory behind all these pointers get allocated? Who is responsible for deallocating it? If it isn't me, how long can I count on the data being valid and how do I avoid leaks?

My se translator routine currently looks like this:

```
void se_translator(unsigned int exception_code, struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS* exception_information) {
    _clearfp();
    throw se_exception(exception_code, exception_information);
};
```

And the worry here is either that all the data pointed to within `exception_information` will be out of scope inside my `catch`es, or that they will all leak somehow.

If there's some documentation that discusses this, I'd like to be pointed to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stack. The exception record is pushed on the stack before the exception is raised. See [A Crash Course on the Depths of Win32™ Structured Exception Handling](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0197/exception/exception.aspx). EXCEPTION_POINTERS is a Visual C++ specific extension to the SEH's EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION:

> Immediately below its extended EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION structure,
>   Visual C++ pushes two additional values. In the DWORD immediately
>   below, it reserves space for a pointer to an EXCEPTION_POINTERS
>   structure (a standard Win32 structure). This is the pointer returned
>   when you call the GetExceptionInformation API.

In fact SEH uses only stack structures because under exception conditions is the <strike>only</strike> most reliable memory allocator. Is not foul-proof (if there is no stack space for the exception record, your process vanishes w/o a trace) but is the best there is.

```
 throw se_exception(exception_code, exception_information);
```

> `exception_information` will be out of scope inside my catch

No, it won't. Your stack will look something like this:

```
somefunction_x::`catch block
DispatchException
RaiseException 
<- exception record is here ->
frame that triggered the SEH raise (c++ throw, AV, stack overflow etc)
caller
somefunction_x
caller
threadentrypoint
```

But what you're doing is highly unusual. Normally translators transform the non c++ exceptions like AV (`ExceptionCode` is `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION`) into a specific c++ exception, eg. they inspect the exception record `ExceptionCode` and raise appropriate C++ typed exception.

Comment: So in the case of me using `_set_se_translator()`, all that memory goes bye-bye when the call to my translator routine ends (eg: when the stack is unwound due to me throwing my nifty new se_exception class.) Thus if I want to use any data from `_EXCEPTION_POINTERS`, I'd need to do a deep copy of it first? (To clarify my concern, I edited my question a smidge).

Comment: the memory goes bye by much later. Your translator runs before the handlers, then the handlers, then the stack unwinds, and only then, as part of the unwinding, is the memory reclaimed. If you look at a debugger backtrace when you're handling an exception you will see that the actual exception raise is 10-20 frames *below* the current one (at least in a debugger like Windbg that hides nothing).

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `EXCEPTION_POINTERS` per se, is not the same as the exception record (which I know better), from Matt's article it seems that is related to the `EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION` (ie. an *exception frame*). That would also be way lower on the stack that anything you touch during the exception handling (including the translator). However, the member pointers are very clearly the exception record and the context itself.

Comment: Now that being said, I must warn you that you *are* playing with napalm here. Is highly unusual to want to save info from the exception pointers for later, why do you need it?

Comment: I'm saving it so the (C++) exception handler can properly decide what to do. For example, if the exception happens to be the head of a chain of `ExceptionRecord`s, the C++ `catch` handler (possibly at the thread's outermost scope) might want to display the entire chain to help the poor developer track down the issue.